# Find null or empty values in AJAX Response

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
{"prepaymentList":[{"years":1,"bps":null,"targetRate":0.0236187,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":""},{"years":2,"bps":null,"targetRate":0.0236187,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":""},{"years":3,"bps":null,"targetRate":0.0236187,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":""},{"years":4,"bps":null,"targetRate":0.0236187,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":""},{"years":1,"bps":null,"targetRate":0.0186187,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":""},{"years":2,"bps":null,"targetRate":0.0186187,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":""},{"years":3,"bps":null,"targetRate":0.0186187,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":""},{"years":4,"bps":null,"targetRate":0.0186187,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":""}],"keyRateList":[{"years":1,"bps":null,"targetRate":null,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":"2.51506"},{"years":2,"bps":null,"targetRate":null,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":"3.03467"},{"years":3,"bps":null,"targetRate":null,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":"3.48070"},{"years":4,"bps":null,"targetRate":null,"TotalValueString":"","ShockString":"","KeyRate":"3.87485"}],"stillRunning":true,"prepaymentLength":5}
```

This is my AJAX response coming back from my JQuery ajax call. How do I go through this and see if I still have null or empty things in there using JQuery?

Comment: First are you sure that this is being returned as a json object not a text string? use the .ajax complete callback with this function:  `function(e){console.log(e);}`. Make sure that when you look at the response in firebug, it's an object not a string...

Comment: it's returning in this sort of format : return Json(new
                    {
                        prepaymentList = "",
                        keyRateList = "",
                        stillRunning = false,
                        prepaymentLength = ""
                    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each(prepaymentList, function(index, value) {
    if (value == null || value == ' ') {
        alert(index+" is null!");
    }
}
```

Untested.

Comment: This stops the whole thing from running at all now. When I comment it out it at least tries to run